# Changing the class to beamer does not specify the color dash line! How to fix the problem?

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50170/algorithm2e-drawing-vertical-dashed-rules/50180#50180)

Changing the class to **beamer** does not specify the color dash line! How to fix the problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\definecolor{algoColorKeyword}{named}{blue}
\definecolor{algoColorComment}{named}{olive}

\renewcommand{\KwSty}[1]{{\color{algoColorKeyword}\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\CommentSty}[1]{{\color{algoColorComment}\texttt{#1}}}

\makeatletter

\def\algocf@Hlne{%
  \hbox{\leaders \hbox{\vrule width 3pt height 0.6pt depth 0pt \hskip 2pt } \hskip 10pt}}


\def\mydashbox#1#2{%
\setbox0\hbox{#2}%
\dimen0\ht0
\advance\dimen0\dp0
\setbox2\vbox to \dimen0{{\color{#1}\leaders\vbox{\vskip2pt\hrule height 3pt width .6pt}\vfill}}%
\ht2=\ht0
\dp2=\dp0
\box2
\unhbox0
}

% The following lines come from algorithm2e.sty
%
% Block with a vertical line end by a little horizontal line
        \renewcommand{\algocf@Vline}[1]{%
                \strut\par\nointerlineskip%t
                \algocf@push{\skiprule}%
                \hbox{%
%                        {\color{algoColorKeyword}\vrule}% HERE !
\mydashbox{algoColorKeyword}{%
                        \vtop{%
                                \algocf@push{\skiptext}%
                                \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal\advance\hsize by -\skiplength #1}%
                                {\color{algoColorKeyword}\Hlne}% HERE !
                        }%
}
                }\vskip\skiphlne%
                \algocf@pop{\skiprule}%
                \nointerlineskip%
        }

% The following lines come from algorithm2e.sty
%
% Block with a vertical line
        \renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%
                \strut\par\nointerlineskip%
                \algocf@push{\skiprule}%
                \hbox{%
%                        {\color{algoColorKeyword}\vrule}% HERE !
\mydashbox{algoColorKeyword}{%
                        \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%
                        \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal\advance\hsize by -\skiplength #1}}%
                }%
}
                \algocf@pop{\skiprule}%
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\scriptsize

\begin{algorithm}[H]
        \tcp{Un exemple d'algorithme haut en couleur...}
        \BlankLine
        \KwData{Données au départ}
        \KwResult{Ce que fait cet algorithme}
        \BlankLine
        \While{La boucle doit continuer}{
                \eIf{Condition 1}{
                        \tcp{Un tout premier test...}
                        Action 1 \\
                        Action 2
                }{
                        \For{$i = 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
                                Calcul $i$ \\
                                Action $i$
                        }
                        \tcp{
                                Un autre test \\
                                plus compliqué...
                        }
                        \uIf{Condition 2}{
                                Action $l + 1$ \\
                                Action $l + 2$
                        }
                        \ElseIf{Condition 3}{
                                Action $l + 3$ \\
                                Action $l + 4$
                        }
                }
        }

        \caption{Un exemple d'algorithme}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output: **TL2019** and **TL2018**
if `\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}`

[image]

Edit: Output **Texlive 2015 with XeLatex**
if `\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}`
[image]

output: **TL2015 with Xelatex if**

```
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
```

[image]

But in TL2015 with PdfLatex, output like TL2019.

Comment: Putting the fragile option in the frame didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the command `\mydashbox` to

```
\def\mydashbox#1#2{%
  \setbox0\hbox{#2}%
  \dimen0\ht0
  \advance\dimen0\dp0
                          % delete \color{#1} in next line
  \setbox2\vbox to \dimen0{\leaders\vbox{\vskip2pt\hrule height 3pt width .6pt}\vfill}%
  \ht2=\ht0
  \dp2=\dp0
  % add \textcolor in next line
  \textcolor{#1}{\box2}%
  \unhbox0
}
```

fixes your problem. Currently I do not know the "why" part.